# Is there any library or hack to make spring beans configurations through JSON instead of XML?

Tags: spring

Is there any library or hack to make spring beans configurations through JSON instead of XML? I mean a java application driven by JSON configurations instead of XML.

Comment: Why use external configuration at all for beans? Especially if you're using Spring Boot there's no need for it. Or are you supporting some legacy spring code in a spring boot application?

Comment: @Gregg sorry, I updated the tag. I was not aware of difference between spring and spring boot.